# Remove from List while !=2

Tags: java

I am learning Java and cannot figure out my problem.

I have a list that will vary in size. What I want to do is, is remove from that list until the size is = 2.

What I have is:

```
int content = list.size() - 1;

while(list.size() !=2){
list.remove(content);
}
```

But I get the exception: IndexOutOfBoundsException. Index 9, size 9

(This index, size will change sometimes depending on content)

Any suggestions to how I can keep iterating through the list until only 2 elements are left?

Thanks

Comment: You need to decrement `content` otherwise its value won't change.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Really you need

```
while (list.size() > 2){
    list.remove(content--);
}
```

1. `> 2` means the algorithm is stable if the size is initially less than 2.
2. You need to decrease `content` when you remove an element.

Answer (score 1):

You never decremented content, so it will never become 2.

```
int content = list.size() - 1;

while(list.size() !=2){
  list.remove(content);
  content = content -1; 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use the following implementation.

```
while(list.size() !=2 ){
    list.remove(list.size() - 1);
}
```

However, this would not work if the list contains one or zero elements; these cases could be covered as follows.

```
while(list.size() > 2 ){
    list.remove(list.size() - 1);
}
```